# Android studio font size changing

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, font-size

My android studio editor's font size was changed to very larger by a mistake, now it is showing very larger on my screen and i can't see where can i change font size. please help me to solve this mistake.

I tried to resize it but not worked

Answer (score 0):

Just go to setting from File to Settings

[image: Change font size from here]

If it answered your question, then don't delete your question, and accept this as an answer